# Hazelcast MapStore Load with TTL

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is there any way to [load](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapLoader.html#load%28K%29) a map entry with a [custom TTL](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#set%28K,%20V,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) using a `MapStore`?

Use Case: My map entries each have a custom expiration, at which point the entry is no longer valid (the TTL is not just for limiting the size of the in-memory map, and the TTL is applied to each entry, not to the map config). I set this TTL when I initially [put](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#set%28K,%20V,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) my entry in the map, the expiration is persisted in my underlying persistent map datastore, but I cannot reset this TTL when loading my entries from the database.

```
public class MyMapStore implements MapStore<MayKey, MapValue> {

    @Override
    public MapValue load(MayKey key) {
        MapValue value = datstore.lookup(key);
        Date ttl = value.getExpiration();
        // the value has it's own entry-specific TTL, but it seems this can't be used from the MapStore
        return value;
    }

    // . . .

}
```

The [`MapLoader`](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapLoader.html) documentation seems to indicate this may not be possible:

> Loaded entries will be placed into the distributed map and they will
>   stay in-memory until they are explicitly removed or implicitly evicted
>   (if eviction is configured).

If there is no way to accomplish this with `MapStore`, some remaining options seem to be:

- Do not use `MapStore` and instead explicitly lookup entries from my
  persistent datastore, loading these values with the desired TTL

  - This may be feasible, but with this approach, I'm no longer able to take
    advantage of the benefits of `MapStore`
- Run a background thread which periodically explicitly evicts these expired entries, rather than relying on Hazelcast's automatic eviction

  - This is just a lot of overhead (additional thread, querying and entry processing) and requires that my application code checks the validity of the entry prior to use (since expired entries may exist in the map)

Is there any other way to accomplish this cleanly/easily with Hazelcast that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 3.6 of Hazelcast, there is not a good way to accomplish this, so I will need to use one of the alternatives identified in the original post.

[Hazelcast Issue 7728](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/7728) has been logged to address this.

See the [Hazelcast Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/j27QsD3GdDc) for related discussions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check : http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#understanding-map-eviction

Evicting Specific Entries
The eviction policies and configurations explained above apply to all the entries of a map. The entries that meet the specified eviction conditions are evicted.

But you may want to evict some specific map entries. In this case, you can use the ttl and timeunit parameters of the method map.put(). An example code line is given below.

myMap.put( "1", "John", 50, TimeUnit.SECONDS )

The map entry with the key "1" will be evicted 50 seconds after it is put into myMap.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I use when I first put entries into the map, but the problem is that I cannot use this method when loading entries with the MapStore.